# GDB does not stop at assembly code address

Tags: linux, debugging, assembly, linux-kernel, gdb

I'm debugging the 32 bit Linux Kernel remotely with GDB and Qemu i386. My GDB script looks like this:

```
target remote localhost:10000
source .
symbol-file vmlinux
set width 0
set height 0
set verbose off

b rest_init
commands
continue
end

b console_init
commands
continue
end

b start_kernel
commands
continue
end

b startup_32
commands
continue
end

continue
```

Now apparently I'm missing something, since the breakpoints in C land, that is `start_kernel`, `console_init`, `rest_init` are recognized as breakpoints and thus jumped at by GDB just fine.

What does not work is the breakpoint on `startup_32`, which is still in Assembly land. GDB just jumps over it as if it wasn't called, but it is definitely called since it's the 32-bit kernel entrypoint.

Is this due to some real-mode/protected-mode fiddlings?

Comment: "startup_32" is called during "kernel loading stage". And "start_kernel" gets called during "Kernel startup stage", which is a call after "startup_32". And GDB "GDB assigns a number to each breakpoint or watchpoint when you create it; these numbers are successive integers starting with one." Try swapping those two calls. I mean set break point to "startup_32" first and next to "start_kernel".

Comment: @PavanChandaka I just tried what you suggested, but it does not work either. The order of how I write down the breakpoints does not have any influence, so `start_kernel` is triggered before `rest_init` etc.

Comment: gdb does some prologue analysis to try to decide where exactly to set the breakpoint.  Since this function is assembly, maybe this isn't working properly.  You can check by disassembling and comparing the breakpoint's reported location to the code.  If that's the problem, try `break *startup_32` -- the `*` means not to try to skip the prologue.

Comment: @TomTromey Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem either, I just tried it.